# Magento 2 - Admin ACL Access Control Lists

Tags: magento2

I have problem with Admin ACL Access Control Lists.

When I switch to module for url `/magento_listingwizard/scanimage/index`
everything goes well, but when I use `/magento_listingwizard/scanimage/new/` I have a problem with permissions.

Comment: check if role resources is checked for the user  for scanimage/new

Comment: Could you add some example code of your controller actions and acl.xml?